# onTouch is registered right after LongTouch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I have a ListView that when I hold (long touch) on an item, the item is removed from the list.

It's registering a touch right after, while the long touch is still happening.

Here is my code -

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("placeNumber", i);
                intent.putExtra("Type", "Fav");

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("Removing", "" + favouriteLocations.get(position));
                favouriteLocations.remove(position);
                Favourites.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }

        });
```

After letting go of long touch a 'phantom' touch appears on the item where the long touch had been (a new item has moved up in the list) and the activity loads as if it has been touched.

It worked fine at one point, I'm sure I didn't change the code. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You're setting the OnTouchListener to the whole ListView, not for each item, is this what you really want?. Maybe would be easier to notify the data changes inside the OnItemLongClickListener and remove the OnTouchListener. Cheers!

Comment: I'm new to all this, so forgive me if I get things wrong, but I had only put onTouchListener there to detect when a touch stops.  I now realise any touch is going to now delay for a second, right? I'll edit that out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `return true` from the `long click listner`, you must have this in the xml too `android:longClickable="true"` but list view is **long clickable by default** so no need to update xml at all.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :-)